# making a checkbox unchecked using .find()

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hi is there A way in which I can make a checkbox uncheck using `.find()` in jQuery.

I can set the value to blank:

```
  $eleme.find("input:checkbox").val("");
```

but I was hoping to set the fact that is check to false. any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use jQuery 1.6+, you should make use of the [prop()](http://api.jquery.com/prop/) method:

```
$eleme.find("input:checkbox").prop('checked', false); //uncheck
$eleme.find("input:checkbox").prop('checked', true); //check
```

Otherwise make use of the [attr()](https://api.jquery.com/attr/) method

```
$eleme.find("input:checkbox").attr('checked', false); //uncheck
$eleme.find("input:checkbox").attr('checked', true); //check
```

Answer (score 2):

use the [`prop`](http://api.jquery.com/prop/#prop2) helper eg. `$eleme.find("input:checkbox").prop( "checked", true );`